# Using the Lookupset function for 3 datasets in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

How can I use Lookupset function in SSRS with 3 datasets

```
=LookupSet(Fields!Account_Number.Value,Fields!Account_Number.Value,
  Fields!Referral_Date_Created,"ReferralsDS")
  (LookupSet(Fields!Account_Number.Value,Fields!Account_Number.Value,
     Fields!Referral_Date_Created,"ReferralsDS").Length -1)
```

Comment: A sample of every dataset could be useful. Also in the expression you are using I only see one dataset ReferralsDS.

Comment: 1st data set has the Account Number, First Name, Last Name

Comment: 1st data set has the Account Number, First Name, Last Name.  2nd data set has Account Number, Last Review Date.  3rd Data Set has Account Number and Discharge Plan Date.  All I want to do is link Data set 1 and Data Set 3 so I can place the Discharge Plan Date on the report.  I have already linked Data set 1 and Data set 2 but cannot figure out how to do DS 3.

Comment: =LookupSet(Fields!Account_Number.Value,Fields!Account_Number.Value,Fields!Review_Last_Modified_On_Date.Value,"UTReviews") (LookupSet(Fields!Account_Number.Value,Fields!Account_Number.Value,Fields!Review_Last_Modified_On_Date.Value,"UTReviews").Length -1)

Comment: You can join all datasets using Account_Number field. How do you want to present the data? I don't understand why are you using lookupset function.

Comment: Maybe I'm going at this all wrong.  This is a hosted application and they won't allow us to us SSMS to create a query or SP.  Can I go this within the query window in SSRS?

Comment: You can use pure SSRS function to join the three datasets. The question is how you want to present the data?